# How does the Aurelia Template Language work

Tags: aurelia

Why the Aurelia HTML syntax looks so similar to the [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) (apart from being an elegant template convention for JS, Python, etc.)?
That isn't really Template literals (behind the scenes), is it?
How does it work? Would be possible to use a different syntax (e.g. `{{ message }}`) and where to start?

Thank you.

Comment: All starts here: https://github.com/aurelia/templating-binding/blob/61dbd989ea33a48544245cafe01f95eb54bad175/src/binding-language.js#L89 - I think its a bit of a broad question to be answered correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aurelia tries to be as standards compliant as possible.
Template literals look exactly like ES sting interpolation for that reason.

It is possible to use handlebars syntax..

skip to 39 minutes in to get your mind blown
https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Seth-on-the-Road/DevIntersection-2015/Rob-Eisenberg-on-Aurelia

Comment: I like Aurelia for the conventions it uses but on the other hand, I need to escape the interpolation (`\${message}`) when using `@inlineView`. This is why I was curious.

Comment: join the https://discourse.aurelia.io/ to keep in touch with the community.

Comment: Can't believe I actually hadn't seen that video before. Great to watch, even now 2.5 years later. Thanks!